# Random Number in Python from a Specific Set

Tags: python, list, random

I want to generate random ints from 4 specific numbers (1,2,5,10).
I only want the output to be one of these. How?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

Comment: [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `choice` method:

```py
random.choice([1, 2, 5 ,10])
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.choice` like so:

```py
import random

nums = [1, 2, 5, 10]
print(random.choice(nums)) # prints either 1, 2, 5, or 10
```

You can view more at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice